# how to replace message payload in spring integration transformer

Tags: spring-integration

I am using `Spring Integration` for my application. I have one `Transformer` which is accepting a file object as a message payload and returning a `GenericMessage` having java pojo as payload.
E.g. my `transform` method is accepting parameter as `Message<?>` and for now I am creating new message using `GenericMessage<List<JavaPOJO>>` to return the message.

My question is, how to change the payload of incoming message?
Because if we are creating new message then the previous message will still be there in memory and this will lead to memory leak.
Please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages are immutable by design; you can't change the payload (although the payload itself may or may not be immutable.

There will be no "memory leak" - that's what the garbage collector is for - unreferenced objects are removed automatically.

Also, generally, you should not be dealing with `GenericMessage` directly; your transformer can have a POJO signature...

```
public MyObject transform(File file) { 
    ...
}
```

Let the framework take care of all the messaging aspects.